# Anyway to find out the current Windows is in lock mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a windows application written in VS 2005. The application makes queries against to sql database in a timer cycle every 2 minutes. If there any data changes, the window will be refreshed with new data.

If the user leaves the window, the windows will be automatically locked after a while. There is no sense to keep querying data in ever 2 minutes when the windows is locked; therefore I would like to stop the query when lock is on so that the network data trafic will be reduced and also saves the current windows resources such as memory and CPUs.

I am not sure if there is any way to find out the current windows is locked? Not sure if there is any Windows APIs for this purpose if no .Net classes available?

My project is in .Net 2.0 and all users are in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want to query whether windows is *locked*, instead what you want to query is whether your application is *visible* - there's no point refreshing your data if the window is minimized or covered by another window either, right?

The standard way to go about this is via a timer and invalidating the window. Use [the Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to schedule a timer 2 minutes into the future. When the timer fires invalidate your window via [Form.Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invalidate.aspx).

When you invalidate the window, Windows will send it a "paint" message. In the `OnPaint` handler, you update the screen with your data. But here's the kicker: if your window is not visible, Windows will *not fire the `OnPaint` event* (that includes if the screen is currently locked)!

Now, your database query is probably a bit too expensive to execute in a `OnPaint` event handler, so you might have to do something tricky in your timer handler. For example, you might do the database query in your timer handler and *then* call `Form.Invalidate()`. This means when you come back from locking the screen, your data might be out-of-date so you could have a check to see whether `DateTime.Now` is significantly different between the timer handler and the `OnPaint` handler and schedule another timer straight away if it is. Otherwise, schedule the timer to run again in 2 minutes from your `OnPaint` callback.

I hope all that makes sense :)

Comment: quite a few APIs to be declared. Not sure if there are some wrapper classes available?

Comment: Not that I know of. In reality, it's actually pretty simple. My description probably just makes it seem more complicated :)

Comment: sorry to get back on this issue late. Now I am back on this again. Based on your description, what I can do is to disable timer at the entrance of its event, do the database queries next. After the queries are done, I call this.Invalidate(). The timer will only enabled in the override of OnPaint(). Am I on the right track?